# (jQuery Autocomplete) Disable keyboard commands?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, autocomplete, keyboard-events

I'm building a custom jQuery-ui autocomplete for Wordpress. Entering a searchterm (in input id="s")lists all suggestions, sorted/filed under categories and by clicking on a list-item, links to the respective page. (The page will be loaded via .load)

So far everything works, but the autocomplete has a built-in keyboard function. I will need to remove all keyboard functionalities. By default, pressing the Up/Down-arrow keys, the previous/next list-item will be focused and the input field gets the value of the focused list-item.

```
For example:
Entering "searchterm" could give the list:
   Suggestion-item 1
   Suggestion-item 2
   Suggestion-item 3
   Suggestion-item 4

Pressing the down-key will replace "searchterm" with "Suggestion-item-1", etc.
Pressing Enter would select the currently focused item and close the menu.
```

Can someone help me on how to remove all these keyboard-functionalities (see on [jQuery Autocomple -> Keyboard Interactions](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/))?

Basically I only want to take the user to an own search-results page with the initially entered "searchterm", if Enter is pressed. Which would be the default behaviour of the search-input.

Here's my js:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {

    // Modify Autocomplete structure
    $.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

        // How to render items
        _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
            //.append( "<div style='display: inline-block; width: 100px;'>" + item.number + "</div><div style='display: inline-block; width: 600px;'>" + item.label + "</div>" )
            .append(    "<article class='project' role='article'>" +  
                        "<header class='project-header'>" + 
                        "<h2 class='project-number col1'>" + "[&thinsp;#&thinsp;" + item.number + "&thinsp;]" + "</h2>" +
                        "<a href='" + item.link + "' rel='bookmark'>" + 
                        "<h2 class='project-title col2'>" + "[&thinsp;#&thinsp;" + item.label + "&thinsp;]" + "</h2>" +                         
                        "</a>" + 
                        "</header>" + 
                        "</article>")
            .appendTo( ul );
        },

        // How to render list
        _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var that = this;
            var currentTag = "";
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                var li;
                if(item.tag != currentTag) {
                    ul.append(  "<li class='acsearch-tag'>" + 
                                "<h2 class='col2'>" + item.tag + "</h2>" +
                                "</li>");
                    currentTag = item.tag;
                }
                li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                if(item.tag) {
                    li;
                }
            });
        }

    });

    var url = MyAutocomplete.url + "?action=my_search";
    // Bind autocomplete to any future instances
    $(document).on('focus', '#s:not(ui-autocomplete-input)', function(event) {
        // Autocomplete function
        $(this).autocomplete({
            appendTo: '#acsearchlist',
            position: { my:'left top', at:'left top', of:'#acsearchlist' },
            source: url,
            delay: 100,
            minLength: 3,
            response: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log(ui);
            },
            open: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#list').hide();
                $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '100%');
            },
            close: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#list').show();
            },
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            messages : {
                noResults : "",
                results : ""
                // function(count) {
                //  return count + (count > 1 ? ' recordings' : ' recording ') + ' found for ';
                // }
            },
            // Page transition on "selected" item
            select: function (event, ui) {
                history.pushState({}, '', ui.item.link);
                console.log(ui.item.link);
                acAjaxLoad(ui.item.link);
            }
        });     
    });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Thanks!

Comment: So to clarify, you _don't_ want the behavior that jQuery UI of pushing enter _only_ filling in the form and not submitting it?

Comment: Yes, basically I want that pushing enter only submits the form (as it's sopposed to do without autocomplete-ui). Furthermore, I tried setting the 'focus' event of .autocomplete to `event.preventDefault();`, which prevents it from updating the input field. But (curiously?) adds the label of the focused item to a `<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">` before the input-field. I would just remove this `<span>`, but need it, as it also contains informations on how many results where found.

Comment: I don't know much about jQuery UI, I would read through the code that powers it and if possible and see if you can attach a function to that keyboard event, otherwise, I would roll your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth 3 years later. This is to stop the input from getting a new value:

```
$('#input').autocomplete({
focus: function( event, ui ) {
  // Stop the autocomplete of resetting the value to the selected one
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

});